# Sharing a Windows 7 music library with a Mac?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, osx-leopard, media-server

I'm running a file server with Windows 7 on it. It does SMB (somewhat unreliably) and media sharing with Homegroup. It serves a music collection using both these methods, but I'm not sure how to go about adding my music library to my girlfriend's iTunes/Mac (OS X Leopard).

I would like to avoid SMB (Windows file shares).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to install iTunes on your win7 and import your music into that.

iTunes can then share it (using bonjour I believe) to other iTunes on the local network, it happened without any configuration when I tried it.

A downside is that iTunes needs to be running on your win7 all the time.

Comment: Having been a bit annoyed with iTunes a few years back, I have to ask: does it still try to rearrange my files and add metadata? I would try this only if it will leave my library unchanged.

Also, does it have the option to run in the tray? That would help a lot.

Comment: I can answer those questions myself, since I installed it just to give it a go. It does leave files and metadata alone if you configure it to, and it does have the option to minimize to the tray (albeit with a badly rescaled icon). It fits the bill, although other answers are still welcome.

Comment: iTune *is* better behaved nowadays (A few years ago it was horrible on windows) still room for improvement of course but it gets a little bit better after each update.